# Вращение куба вокруг заданной точки

Tags: c++, directx

Суть в следующем - есть меш, обычный куб, сгенерированный функцией "D3DXCreateBox", мне необходимо вращать его вокруг заданной точки, я пытался использовать D3DXMatrixRotationX,Y,Z, и даже  проверил на всякий случай поворот вокруг своей оси "D3DXMatrixRotationAxis" - но результат один и тот же куб вращается вокруг собственной левой, верхей или верхней левой грани, это если использовать "D3DXMatrixRotationX", "D3DXMatrixRotationY" и  "D3DXMatrixRotationZ" соответственно, также себя ведет и с функцией "D3DXMatrixRotationAxis". 
Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в библиотеке функция которая может вращать мой куб вокруг заданной точки, на заданном радиусе, или же все же тут нужно рассчитывать вручную синусами и косинусами? 
Пример кода:

```
ID3DXBuffer* cubeBuf;
  ID3DXMesh* tempCube;
  ID3DXMesh* cube;
  D3DXCreateBox(d3d9.pDirect3DDevice, 2, 2, 2, &cube, &cubeBuf);

  if (!(cube->GetFVF() & D3DFVF_DIFFUSE))
  {
    if (cube->CloneMeshFVF(D3DXMESH_MANAGED, D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE, d3d9.pDirect3DDevice, &tempCube) != D3D_OK) {

      msg_er_full;
    }
    cube->Release();  
    cube = tempCube; 
  }

  Vertex_XYZ_Color * buf;

  D3DXMATRIX outMat;
  D3DXMatrixIdentity(&outMat);

  D3DXVECTOR3 out;
  D3DXVECTOR3 coord;

  cube->LockVertexBuffer(0, (void**)&buf);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < text->GetNumVertices(); i++)
    {
      coord = { buf[i]._x, buf[i]._y, buf[i]._z };
      D3DXMatrixRotationX(&outMat, degree_to_radian(1));

      D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&out, &coord, &outMat);

      buf[i]._x = out.x;
      buf[i]._y = out.y;
      buf[i]._z = out.z;
    }

  cube->UnlockVertexBuffer();
```